# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fol for class: WorkflowScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline which uses a shared library. I have few build parameters in which one of them is `DynamicReferenceParameter` which is of type `ET_FORMATTED_HTML`. I am trying to dynamically update the input field by calculating the actual value as shown below.

Please look into `vSphere_Folder` parameter section in the below code.

```
@Library('sdUtilLib') _

pipeline {
agent {
    label val
}
stages {
stage('Set parameters') {
        steps {
            script {
                dcVars = new DCVars()
                currentBuild.displayName = '#' + currentBuild.number +
                                            '-' + params.Datacenter +
                                            '_CUST_' + params.Customer_Number
                properties([
                    parameters([
                        choice(
                            name: 'Environment',
                            choices: dcVars.getENVList(),
                            description: 'Select an Environment'
                        ),
                        choice(
                            name: 'Customer_Number',
                            choices: dcVars.getCustList(),
                            description: ''
                        ),
                        string(
                            defaultValue: '', 
                            description: '', 
                            name: 'Customer_Name', 
                            trim: true
                        ),
                        [
                            $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
                            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                            description: 'Select a Datacenter',
                            filterLength: 1,
                            filterable: false,
                            name: 'Datacenter',
                            randomName: 'choice-parameter-1434774074254', 
                            referencedParameters: 'Environment', 
                            script: [
                                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                                fallbackScript: [
                                    classpath: [],
                                    sandbox: true,
                                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                                ],
                                script: [
                                    classpath: [],
                                    sandbox: true,
                                    script: """
                                       def choices
                                       def dcmap = ${dcVars.envMap.inspect()}
                                       choices = dcmap[Environment]
                                       return choices"""
                               ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                            choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                            description: '',  
                            name: 'vSphere_Folder', 
                            randomName: 'choice-parameter-1434753243254', 
                            referencedParameters: 'Datacenter, Customer_Number, folder', 
                            script: [
                                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                fallbackScript: [
                                    classpath: [], 
                                    sandbox: true, 
                                    script: ''
                                ], script: [
                                    classpath: [], 
                                    sandbox: true, 
                                    script: """
                                        def dcmap = ${dcVars.dcMap.inspect()}
                                        def scmap = ${dcVars.scMap.inspect()}
                                        def sc = scmap[Datacenter]
                                        def dc = dcmap[sc]
                                        def folders = dc.FOLDER
                                        def fol = folders[0].replaceAll('xxx', Customer_Number)
                                        return <input name=\"value\" value=\"${fol}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">
                                       """
                                ]
                            ],
                            omitValueField: true
                        ]
                    ])
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

If you take a look at parameter vSpehre_Folder, in the return statement I am just returning the variable `fol` which has a specific value.

Even if I assign a string to variable `fol` and use `${fol}` in return statement, it still doesn't work.

But I am getting the below error. Can anyone help?

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fol for class: WorkflowScript
17:30:31    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
17:30:31    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
17:30:31    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:355)
17:30:31    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:354)
17:30:31    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
17:30:31    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
17:30:31    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
17:30:31    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
17:30:31    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
17:30:31    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:221)
17:30:31    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
17:30:31    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
17:30:31    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:30:31    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
17:30:31    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
17:30:31    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
17:30:31    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
17:30:31    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
17:30:31    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
17:30:31    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
17:30:31    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
17:30:31    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
17:30:31    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
17:30:31    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
17:30:31    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
17:30:31    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
17:30:31    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
17:30:31  Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: `rerurn <input ....` is incorrect. Use `rerurn "<input name='value' ....` for example

Comment: Also `${fol}` references outer script variable. You have to escape it `\${fol}`

Comment: look its scope is not while running script if you escape ${fol} it should work